# using log_printf in code composer studio

Tags: c, printf

The code compiles and builds properly, but gives no output. Where do i see the ouptput?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <std.h>    
#include <log.h>
#include "Configuration2cfg.h"

extern far LOG_Obj fastprint;   

void main()
{
LOG_printf (&fastprint, "Algorithm 1 is running\n");    
}
```

Comment: There is no standard function named `LOG_printf`, where did you get it from?

Comment: The keyword `far` is not in standard C either.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg... LOG_printf(...) is available in composer studio. See this http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/3329.aspx

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Fww%2Fcn%2Fuprogram%2Fshare%2Fppt%2Fc6000%2FChapter4.ppt&ei=BPINUrHVL-bi4QT4voHYAg&usg=AFQjCNE2mkTHCtkzSKMOi8vSuwO9n81yQg&bvm=bv.50768961,d.bGE) is what i followed (slides 50-54)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to menu Tools --> RTA --> Printf Logs and the messages should be updated.

If not, can you try to run one of the supplied examples with BIOS 5.4x and see if you get output on this screen? This may rule out any issues related to your specific project. For details on how to use the example project, please check:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GSG:Using_BIOS#DSP.2FBIOS_5_Support

Comment: Thnx, the problem was that log messages are only displayed when the target is running. If halted, nothing is displayed